# Set background image to 100% width in Netbiscuits

Tags: mobile, netbiscuits

Has anyone managed to set the background image to 100% width on Net biscuits?

Cheers,
Steph

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in Netbiscuits. The NB image converter will not process / scale a background image